# How do I reduce the number of (the same) characters printed in each line using a loop?

Tags: java, string, loops

Basically, I am trying to print lines of characters, specifically asterisks. Every subsequent line should have one less asterisk than the previous line. Additionally, they should all be aligned to the **right**.
My knowledge of Java is not too strong, so bear with me.

Here's an image of the output and the instructions:

[image]

Comment: You need 2 loops, one inside the other. This looks like a homework dump without any attempt. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.  But this is not a coding tutorial forum.

Comment: Actually, I did try. I attempted to use a for loop, then ran out of ideas because I'm not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can modify the variables as you see fit. Key is to use a bunch of for loops and keep track of all the variables.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //line number your on
    for(int k = 0; k<i;k++)//keeps track of number of spaces to use, line number minus 1 spaces printed
    {
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
for (int j = 8; j >i; j--) {//prints out 8 * and reduced by 1*line number
System.out.print("*"); 
}
System.out.println();//prints new line and initiates new line by i++
}
```

Comment: I should've thought about using loops within loops :S
Reading through this, this makes perfect sense. As amount of spaces increase, amount of asterisks decrease.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off with a simpler example:

```
***
 **
  *
```

What pattern do you see? The pattern is that on each line, the sum of the amount of asterisks and the amount of spaces is constant. I'll call this constant `L` for now on, which stands of the *line length*.
From this, we can infer that `amountOfSpaces` is `L - amountOfAsterisks`, and vice versa (as the magical laws of Algebra also apply here).

So from this, we can deduce that on each line we need to print `L - amountOfAsterisks` spaces first, and then `amountOfAsterisks`. For cases like these, `for` loops are a life-saver (In more professional code (as professional as you can get with fancy terminal graphics) this would be done a bit differently, as in actuality using `for`-loops for such a thing makes the function `O(N)`).

The rest is up to you

Comment: Wow, never thought of it like that. Thank you.